# iPhone UITextView Did End On Exit properties?

Tags: iphone

Why is it that there is no Did End On Exit property for a UITextView?  How do you resignFirstResponder to lower the keyboard when the user clicks the 'Done' button?  A UITextField usually works by just linking 'Did End On Exit' from UIBuilder but UITextView doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most apps solve this problem by adding a button somewhere in your UI. For instance in Safari, when you pop up the Keyboard on a UITextView, it brings a Toolbar with it with Previous, Next, autofill and a Done Button, and the Done button implements [myTextView resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

There is `textViewDidEndEditing`: in the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol that will do what you need I believe.

Comment: textViewDidEndEditing (and the other methods in that section of the delegate) are fired after, not before, textView was told to resign first responder.